# How to construct a function that can be used for mapping a JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] in spark/scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

```
val drdd = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3)).toDF("name", "value").toJavaRDD
drdd.map{ (row: Row) => row.get(0) }
```

It seems like the anonymous function I passed is Row => Any while it is expecting org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,?]

```
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Any
required: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,?]
   drdd.map{ (row: Row) => row.get(0) }
                        ^
```

What is the difference between those function types and how should I construct it? Thanks!

Comment: why would you convert javaRDD and not rdd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
drdd.map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[Row, String]() {
    override def call(row: Row): String = row.getString(0)
})
```

Comment: it works! thanks! I just don't understand why does the scala annoymous functions work in this example?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

  val lineLengths = lines.map(s => s.length)

Comment: This example works, because is using different type RDD and JavaRDD class has different input parameters. Basically I don't understand why in Scala you want to use JavaRDD, you should use Scala RDD.

Comment: oh... I didn't notice they are different classes! I used it because there is a toJavaRDD method. Now I see there is a .rdd method that returns scala RDD. Everything makes sense to me now. Thanks again, Piotr!